# Chrome 87 is failing Windows Authentication in CORS against Windows IIS 10

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, cors, windows-authentication

Chrome 86 (and prior), Edge, Curl, and IE all are able to do cross-origin Windows Authentication against my IIS 10 ASP.NET service on Windows 2019 machine without any problem.

But Chrome 87 fails with "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://[REDACTED]' from origin 'http://[DIFFERENT]' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested"

*Weirdly - Chrome 87 works with the identical ASP.NET service running in IIS 7.5 on a Windows 2008 machine (don't ask) that is configured identically.*

*UPDATE: Note - I realized [2020-12-04] that the "working" system happened to be on a different domain that was already added to my "Sites that can always use cookies" list. So the "fix" was staring me in the face right from the start... ;)*

Using curl - I can't see any difference between the IIS responses for Windows Authentication.

If I hack my ASP.NET and have it include a echoed Access-Control-Allow-Origin 'http://[DIFFERENT]' to all requests instead of the main one - then Chrome 87 barks a 401 - not authorized - instead of continuing with the Windows Authentication back and forth. Curl and the other browsers are just fine with the additional headers.

Invoking the website directly (without cross-origin) works just fine.

Anyone have a clue what Chrome 87 is doing different? The Dev Tools only shows the "last" request in the chain - so I don't know what is happening prior to the failure.

*UPDATE: [2020-12-02]*
*Apparently the Chromium Team is claiming it is working the way it needs to... But it seems weirdly broken to me.*

*https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1154281*

*"This is now expected behavior - blocking third party cookies now acts like setting crendials:omit on third party requests.  We'll see how many reports we get about this, but the previous behavior was buggy, since truly uncredentialed requests and those that had provided HTTP auth credentials, but no cookies, would share sockets."*

Comment: Check if you hit the preflight issue https://blog.lextudio.com/how-to-handle-cors-preflight-requests-in-asp-net-mvc-web-api-with-windows-authentication-f19814cbb558 IIS CORS module is a must in such cases.

Comment: That is the thing - I'm not sure what is going on. I have a different site using .NET CORE 3.x with full-blown CORS support. It is, indeed working fine with Chrome 87 cors, but it doesn't do windows authentication - so while I will likely rebuild this problem site in .NET CORE 3.x and add in the CORS support - I'm not even sure that will correct the problem since it isn't clear what is really wrong here.

Comment: Nothing can hide from the network tab https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network Check it for details.

Comment: I am familiar with the DevTools. But when I hit my working site - the network panel only shows the "request" in the Network panel and does not show the Windows authentication request/response back and forth (I assume for security reasons).

Comment: Just found that Google modified Chrome to hide such. Bad move. Then try Fiddler, https://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: To add to the fun... My company uses ZScalar - which makes using Fiddler very tricky. :)

Comment: It looks something to do with 3-th party cookie. If you enable 3th party cookie in Chrome 87, does your webapp work (and windows authentication) ?

Comment: Nice idea, unfortunately no cookies involved - the API service is fully stateless and so doesn't set any cookies - so nothing to "allow".

Comment: I rebuilt using .NET CORE 3.x with the same CORS support as another website that works. But it still yields the same stupid error. Now I'm freaked out.

Comment: @bastienenjalbert - you are correct - see Tom's answer below. That worked.

Comment: @RobinJohnson I see you've added the update from the Chrome bug. That's quite a change to bring in with no warning, and as far as I can see not even a mention in the release notes. I've added a comment to that bug report to add my voice to it.

Comment: @RobinJohnson Yes I saw the answer, we already did that in my organization, like I advised you to try. Sad to lost reputation to a self advised anwser :) let's wait for chrome issue you raised now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We are seeing the same in our environment, Chrome 87 is now applying the cookie rules to Kerberos and NTLM authentication (clearly a bug). This is affecting not just XHR but any resource loaded from another site (images, iframes, etc).

We have "Block third-party cookies" set and have found that adding affected sites and domains to the "Sites that can always use cookies" list in Chrome has restored authentication; and is an acceptable workaround for us since we manage Chrome via Group Policy and can push out an updated list of sites easily.

2020-12-02:
As of today MS Edge 87 exhibits the same behaviour.

Comment: Thanks Tom! That did work. I was going bleary-eyed looking at IIS CORS documentation and it kept talking about cookies (that is the whole threatspace) but I kept thinking BUT I'm not using any cookies... But a buggy Chrome implementation would explain this. I did file a bug report with Chrome - I would like to think they'll fix it.

Comment: @RobinJohnson: Was your issue crbug.com/1154281 ?

Comment: @EricLaw Yep. That is exactly the problem.